# Wait for response with timeout in "Dispatch" library

Tags: scala, http, concurrency, scala-dispatch

I am going to use [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/) to write a simple HTTP client. I call `dispatch.Http` to get a future and call the future to get the response

```
val request = ...
val future = Http(request) // call the server asynchronously
val response = future() // wait for the response from the server
```

Now I wonder how I can wait *with timeout*. I would like the last API call to be:

```
// throw an exception if no response received within timeout
val response = future(timeout: Long)
```

Does it make sense ?

I understand that `Dispatch` return `scala.concurrent.Future`, which does not provide API with timeout. How would you suggest me implement it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can use [Await](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Await%24):

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

Await.result(future, 10 seconds) //you can specify timeout here
```

The problem is that it will throw an exception if the future did not manage to return in specified timeout.

If you need more flexibility here is the second approach:

```
val futureTimeout = Promise.timeout("Timed out" /* or throw new RuntimeException("timed out") */, 10 seconds)
Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(futureResult, futureTimeout)).map {
  case result: SomeType => //do something
  case timedOut: SomeOtherType => //handle timeout
}
```

Comment: Thanks you ! I forgot about `Await` !

Comment: where from you got Promise.timeout ? I don't see it in API: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Promise$ .

Comment: Promise.timeout is specific of the Play framework. It seems this is the link for the documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html

Answer (score 5):

You can create configured Http client:

val httpApplicationClient = Http.configure(
   _.setRequestTimeoutInMs(3000)
 )

val future = httpApplicationClient(request)

...

Comment: `_.setRequestTimeout(3000)` since Async HTTP Client 1.9.

Comment: This can also be done per-request: `req.underlying(_.setRequestTimeout(3000))`

Comment: When I first read this answer, I was unable to find the source of the author's information. After some digging, I found `dispatch`'s javadoc:

https://static.javadoc.io/net.databinder.dispatch/dispatch-core_2.11/0.11.2/index.html#dispatch.Http@configure(withBuilder:com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder=>com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder):dispatch.Http

and piece it together with `AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder`

https://asynchttpclient.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder.html